# Can I query an object in JPA

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa, orm

I m using JPA with Spring Data,

Have a Class Event that has a field `UserDetail createdBy`, I want to query an Event that created by specified User. Here is my query

```
@Query("SELECT e FROM  event WHERE e.created_by = :userdetail")
    Collection<Event> getEventsCreatedByUser(@Param("userdetail")UserDetail user);
```

When I launch tests with this query in Dao class I get an error `org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QuerySyntaxException: event is not mapped [SELECT e FROM  event WHERE e.created_by = :userdetail]`

Here is entity class, the created_by is in BaseEntityAudit, I tested User class that also extends BaseEntityAudit and it worked just fine, also pgadmin shows that the column createdBy exists in Event table

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "Event")
@AttributeOverride(name = "id", column = @Column(name = "event_id",
        nullable = false, columnDefinition = "bigserial"))
public class Event extends BaseEntityAudit {
    @Embedded
    private Point point;    
    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinTable(name = "event_comments")
    private Collection<Comment> comments = new ArrayList<Comment>();
    @OneToMany
    @JoinTable(name = "\"users_tagged_at_event\"")
    private Collection<UserDetail> usersTagged = new ArrayList<UserDetail>();    
    public Event(UserDetail createdBy, Point point) {
        super();
        this.point = point;
        setCreatedBy(createdBy);
    }
```

Also the BaseEntityAudit

```
public abstract class BaseEntityAudit extends BaseEntity {
    @Column(name = "created_at")
    @Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
    private Date createdAt;
    @Column(name = "created_by", length = 20)
    private UserDetail createdBy;
    @Column(name = "updated_at")
    @Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
    private Date updatedAt;
    @Column(name = "updated_by", length = 20)
    private UserDetail updatedBy;
//geters/setters ...
    /**
     * Sets createdAt before insert
     */
    @PrePersist
    public void setCreationDate() {
        this.createdAt = new Date();
   }
    /**
     * Sets updatedAt before update
     */
    @PreUpdate
    public void setChangeDate() {
        this.updatedAt = new Date();
    }
}
```

UPDATE

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: org.hibernate.QueryException: could not resolve property: created_by of: home.map.events.entity.Event [SELECT e FROM  home.map.events.entity.Event e WHERE e.created_by = :userdetail]
```

Comment: Post `event` entity class.

Comment: YOU haven't got a field "created_by" ... you have "createdBy"!!!

Comment: @NeilStockton already did this on update...

Comment: No you haven't because if you had done that you wouldn't get that message ... since there would be no "created_by" in your Query.

Comment: @NeilStockton got u, thank u

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You forgot to mention `event e` in from clause. I guess you have event table and Event class (pointed out by **@pL4Gu33**). So you need to use **Event** instead of **event**.

```
@Query("SELECT e FROM Event e WHERE e.createdBy = :userdetail")
                use---^     ^- added      ^---- updated
```

Comment: did what u advised, even specified @Table(name = "Event") for the table I`m querying, but it didn`t work..

Comment: what is your table name and entity name? And post your event entity class.

Comment: done, can this mistake be because of field created_by being in BaseEntityAudit?

Comment: In the query, change it to `createdBy` instead of `created_by`.

Comment: sorry forgot to mention, this already done, you can see this in UPDATE

Comment: Stack trace : `SELECT e FROM  home.map.events.entity.Event e WHERE e.created_by = :userdetail` still mentions `e.created_by` instead of `e.createdBy`. Check the updated query in the answer.

Answer (score 1):

Your class is 'Event' not 'event' and have a look on Naman Gala answer, too.